# Реализация контекстного меню PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, меню

Подскажите как реализовать контекстное меню в виджете как у `QTextEdit` нашел в [доках про `QContextMenuEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcontextmenuevent.html#QContextMenuEvent), но как это реализовать на примере не понимаю. Попробовал сам реализовать, но толкового ничего не получилось.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ContextMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('привет')
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)

    def openMenu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        addDes = QtWidgets.QAction('Открыть', menu)
        menu.addAction(addDes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = ContextMenu()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сигнал [customContextMenuRequested](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) нужно передавать метод с параметром, который получит позицию (`QPoint`) и по этой позиции останется вызывать меню. Меню можно составить заранее, либо прямо в методе `show_context_menu`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw


class ContextMenuWidget(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('ContextMenuWidget')

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)

        self.menu = qtw.QMenu(self)
        action = self.menu.addAction('Say: "Hello!"')
        action.triggered.connect(lambda: qtw.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', 'Hello!'))

    def show_context_menu(self, point):
        self.menu.exec(self.mapToGlobal(point))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication([])

    root = ContextMenuWidget()
    root.resize(400, 400)
    root.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: а как сделать отделение т.е. вот в примере (на скрине)  там есть контекстное меню где есть линия разделение `ctrl+z, ctrl+y` как так же это сделать?

Comment: Вы про http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addSeparator ?

Comment: Скорее я что то делаю не правильно но эта функция скрывает кнопку как `setVisible` в меню

Comment: У меню вызываете addSeparator и он добавит разделитель между action. Не совсем понял про setVisible. Если непонятно создайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: Разобрался я просто по глупому начал вместо `addSeparator` вводил `setSeparator` к определенной кнопку спасибо